# App does not update even with appAutoUpdatePolicy set to ALWAYS

Tags: android, google-play, android-management-api

Our Android native Companion App is automatically installed on the device upon enrollment. The matching profile entry is:

```
"packageName": "app.domain.companionapp",
"installType": "REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP",
"defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
"managedConfiguration": {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
},

"delegatedScopes": [
  "ENABLE_SYSTEM_APP",
  "PACKAGE_ACCESS"
]
```

We have pushed an update on the Play Store more than a week ago. But the update does not install automatically on the devices, even if the profile allows auto updates (`"appAutoUpdatePolicy": "ALWAYS"`)

I don't see any `nonComplianceDetails` issue regarding the Companion App for the device.

When we launch the Play Store app on the device, we actually see that updates are pending:

[image: Play Store]

How come? How can we be sure that the app update will be automatically installed on the device?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facing the same issue.

We are now using a workaround by pushing the policy again with the latest `minimumVersionCode` of the application with `installType : "FORCE_INSTALLED"`

This will ensure that the app is updated to the specified `minimumVersionCode`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sudhu, that's a nice workaround. Hope we won't have the issue with too many apps, since (according to the documentation): `At most 20 apps may specify a minimum version code per policy.` :)

Comment: Yes that's one thing to be worried about but lets hope google fixes this bug soon so there would be no need for a workaround.

Comment: my app is not updated with this hack.. I have successfully installed the app in Kiosk mode (.installType : "KIOSK") After that, I want to update the app. I settled the policy to installType : "FORCE_INSTALLED" with minimum version code to latest update on Google play but nothing happend. If I press "install" button in in google work account I get the message "Can't Install the apps The settings on this device dosen't allow you to install the apps."   If I switch to intallType Kiosk, "INstalling new app.." screen pops up but progress stays untouched. 0 of 1 app installed.  Any suggestions?