# Android Management provisioned devices don't always install apps

Tags: android-management-api

We enrolled several devices using an Android management api token.
Most of the units provisioned and work correctly. On some, one or more of the applications we want FORCE_INSTALLED don't end up installed. I had the people provisioning these units (Pixel 3a if it matters) reboot the units to see if the apps appeared.
Looking at the device list result there is nonComplianceDetails indicating the apps are in progress installing, but it doesn't seem to happen:

```
    "nonComplianceDetails": [
      {
        "installationFailureReason": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "nonComplianceReason": "APP_NOT_INSTALLED",
        "packageName": "MAIN_APP",
        "settingName": "applications"
      },
      {
        "installationFailureReason": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "nonComplianceReason": "APP_NOT_INSTALLED",
        "packageName": "ANOTHER_APP",
        "settingName": "applications"
      },
      {
        "installationFailureReason": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "nonComplianceReason": "APP_NOT_INSTALLED",
        "packageName": "YET_ANOTHER_APP",
        "settingName": "applications"
      },
```

Any way to get these devices to force the install?

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue which has been around for a while.

I've reported it to Google - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900783/android-device-policy-sync-does-not-work-until-done-manually)

They seem to have fixed it but I am still facing the issues at times.

We are using a workaround by pushing the policy again with the latest minimumVersionCode of the application with `installType : "FORCE_INSTALLED"`

This will ensure that the app is updated to the specified `minimumVersionCode` [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885377/app-does-not-update-even-with-appautoupdatepolicy-set-to-always/56964887)

Answer (score 2):

There may be delays in installing the apps to the device. Other times, apps may already be installed in the device but delay in providing non compliance status. You can also force sync the policy by going to Settings > Google > Work Profile> Device Policy and clicking the Sync icon.

You may also try using the installType `REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP` to have the device download the apps before the setup is completed.